# Expected Value of Random Variable with Parameter

Tags: probability-theory

Say $X_t$ is a random variable with parameter $t$ and $Y$ is another random variable which takes on values in the parameter space for $X_t$.  If I know the distribution of $Y$ and I know the distribution of $X_t$ for any fixed $t$, then how do I compute $\mathbb{E}[X_{Y}]$?
Note that $X_t$ takes on only integer values, but $Y$ is a nonnegative continuous random variable, so I can't just break things up into a sum.  I was thinking of using $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_{k/n})\mathbb{P}(\frac{k-1}{n}\leq Y \leq \frac{k}{n})$$ but I'm not quite sure how to justify this argument, and it's way too computationally intensive

Comment: 1. Is $t\to X_t$ right continuous ? 2. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent ?

Comment: 1.  Yes, and 2.  For each fixed $t$, $X_t$ and $Y$ are indeed independent.

Answer (score 1):

If $(X_t)_t$ and $Y$ are independent then:$$\mathbb EX_Y=\int\mathbb{E}\left(X_{Y}\mid Y=y\right)dF_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int\mathbb{E}X_{y}dF_{Y}\left(y\right)=\mathbb{E}e\left(Y\right)$$
where $e$ is prescribed by $y\mapsto\mathbb{E}X_{y}$.

Comment: It's true that for every fixed $t$, $X_t$ and $Y$ are independent.  Is that what we need?

Comment: I don't know whether it is true. Actually you are the one to find out on base of the context (which is unknown to me). If it is true then you can use this.

Comment: Also there could be another obstacle: the function $e$ must be measurable.

Comment: In this case it is true that for a fixed $t$, $X_t$ and $Y$ are independent.  Is this enough to show that $\mathbb{E}(X_Y)=\mathbb{E}(e(Y))$?

Comment: I say "yes" to that (assuming that $e$ is integrable), but must admit that this "yes" is more based on intuition than on knowledge. I am not very familiar with random processes like $(X_t)_t$. Have you done any effort to calculate yet?

Comment: Yes, and the answer that comes out looks reasonable.  Also, $e$ is $F_Y$-integrable.

Comment: Nice. I would say that you are ready then. I have nothing to offer anymore.